# SQL Joining Query How To

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
CREATE TABLE interview (uniqueID int identity(1,1), 
                        date datetime, 
                        recordtype int, 
                        amount numeric(18, 4))

INSERT INTO interview values('6/30/13', 1, 27.95)
INSERT INTO interview values('5/20/13', 1, 21.85)
INSERT INTO interview values('5/22/13', 2, 27.90)
INSERT INTO interview values('12/11/12', 2, 23.95)
INSERT INTO interview values('6/13/13', 3, 24.90)
INSERT INTO interview values('6/30/13', 2, 27.95)
INSERT INTO interview values('5/20/13', 2, 21.85)
INSERT INTO interview values('5/22/13', 1, 27.90)
INSERT INTO interview values('12/11/12',1, 23.95)
INSERT INTO interview values('6/13/13', 3, 24.90)
INSERT INTO interview values('6/30/13', 3, 27.95)
INSERT INTO interview values('5/20/13', 3, 21.85)
INSERT INTO interview values('5/22/13', 2, 27.90)
INSERT INTO interview values('12/11/12', 1, 23.95)
INSERT INTO interview values('6/13/13', 1, 24.90)
```

How to get the following result?  What would the query look like?

[image: Query Result]

I was only able to get a partial to work, but my answer is not correct.  I need to
somehow join the queries.

```
select distinct date, count(RecordType)as Count_unique1
from interview
where RecordType = '1'
group by date

select distinct date, count(RecordType)as Count_unique2
from interview
where RecordType = '2'
group by date

select distinct date, count(RecordType)as Count_unique3
from interview
where RecordType = '3'
group by date
```

Comment: try this link : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa172756%28v=sql.80%29.aspx

Comment: RecordType will be 1,2,3 in all cases or it may vary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select 
date, 
sum(case when RecordType = '1' then 1 else 0 end) as Count_unique1,
sum(case when RecordType = '2' then 1 else 0 end) as Count_unique2,
sum(case when RecordType = '3' then 1 else 0 end) as Count_unique3
from interview
group by date
```

Answer (score 1):

Also in MSSQL you can use [PIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

```
SELECT date, [1] AS Count_unique1,
             [2] AS Count_unique2,
             [3] AS Count_unique3
FROM (SELECT date,recordtype,amount FROM interview) p
PIVOT
(
  COUNT (amount)
  FOR recordtype IN ([1], [2], [3])
) AS pvt
ORDER BY pvt.date;
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/15978/4)</kbd>

Comment: Msg 325, Level 15, State 1, Line 5
Incorrect syntax near 'PIVOT'. You may need to set the compatibility level of the current database to a higher value to enable this feature. See help for the SET COMPATIBILITY_LEVEL option of ALTER DATABASE.

Answer (score 0):

If RecordType is 1,2 and 3 in all cases this will be enough.

```
select date, 
sum(RecordType = '1') as Count_unique1,
sum(RecordType = '2') as Count_unique2,
sum(RecordType = '3') as Count_unique3
from interview
group by date
```

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near '='.